# Why is onNewIntent() not used together with singleInstance launchmode?

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode, onnewintent

Why is onNewIntent() not used together with singleInstance launchmode? I mean if I re-launch my singleInstance Activity I might still want to get that new Intent, right?

Answer (score 1):

It does get called.

If you launch an `Activity` which has `launchMode="singleInstance"` and that `Activity` is already running in a task, the task will be brought to the foreground and `onNewIntent()` will be called.